# How to find string in table when a expression has any order?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a table

- mama rama drama
- drama mama rama
- rama drama mama

I use a dialog for find and replace in spreadsheet.
I want to find all items at once. How to use a regex for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want as easy as you're thinking. Here are the next best options I can think of.

1) Have every combination in lookaheads, so it'll match just the string you want (i skipped some combinations for brevity)

```
(?=\bmama|rama|drama\b)(?=\brama|mama|drama\b)(?=\bdrama|mama|rama\b).*
```

2) List the words individually inside lookaheads, but it'll match the whole line that contains the words you list in the lookaheads.

```
(?=.*\bmama\b)(?=.*\brama\b)(?=.*\bdrama\b).*
```

This is as good as you'll get I think :)

Comment: If I use expression like "?=" A error returned "Oops. A server error occurred." But your solution is very good and helpfull. Thank you!